# Should node_modules for frontend and backend be separated

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am using node.js and React. I am using npm to manage packages for both front-end and back-end (and using Webpack for the front-end). Should I separate the front-end and back-end modules?

Not separate:

```
root
  node_modules
    (express)
    (mongoose)
    (react)
  public
    App.jsx
  server.js
```

Separate:

```
root
  node_modules
    (express)
    (mongoose)
  public
    node_modules
      (react)
    App.jsx
  server.js
```

I would think that separating is the obvious choice, but I see the non-separate structure a lot, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes typically you want to have your `server` and your `client` in separate folders, otherwise, you can run into some [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues. Also, having your server and client separate makes it easier to deploy the application with containerization programs like [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/).

So your file structure would look something like:

```
./client
  .react
./server
  .express
```

`.express` and `.react` are just shorthand for all of your files in these folders. So you would have separate node_modules folders for each of these directories.

Although if you were using NextJS, in some cases your backend will be saved with your client. This is typically used because of the efficiency of serverless technology. Check out: [NextJS APIs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction).

NextJS may also be used in this form because it is extremely easy to deploy your NextJS application with [Vercel](https://vercel.com).

Overall, the separation of dependencies and files in your server and client will make it much easier to manage your application, within and outside of deployment.

Comment: In this case, where should I put my front-end build tools (like Webpack, Babel)?

Comment: that would just be in your `./client` folder. You can run your react application or whatever library you are using in this folder, and then run your server in another folder. Of course, these two different servers will be running on different ports, so your frontend will make requests to the localhost port of your backend server.

Comment: check out this example on github: https://github.com/mongodb-developer/mern-stack-example it gives a pretty good idea of what you are looking for